# MS Access using "in" is taking forever

Tags: ms-access

In MS Access 2010, I have a table called MyTable with the following fields:

```
visit_id, client_id, associate_id, startTime, StopTime, VisitDate
```

I'd like to find the associates that dont have a visit booked between Time1 and Time2 on a certain date.

my chosen method to is check which associates dont turn up in a query of those that have a visit within that interval, as in the following:

```
Select associate_id from
myTable
Where associate_id not in 
     (select associate_id from Mytable where visitStart <= Time2 AND VisitStop > Time1)
```

This takes forever to run in MS Access 2010, and is not a viable solution.
Is there a more efficient solution in MS Access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try adding the DISTINCT keyword to your subquery.

If that doesn't help you could try something like this:

```
Select associate_id 
From myTable
Group by associate_id
Having sum(IIf(startTime <= Time2 AND StopTime> Time1, 1, 0) = 0
```

You'd still have to filter for VisitDate of course.

Comment: Thank you so much. Using "HAVING" solved my problem.